# Bootstrap margin / padding disapears on adding object via jquery

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a little problem using bootstrap and adding dynamically element on my page.

I've a form where I lwant to dynamically add new inputs. All that work fine but the rendering is not that good because it seems that there is some missing margin padding between the label and the select.

I use bootstrap as main css.

Here is an exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/4Uf2U/1/

```
<div class="form-inline">
<label>Label</label>
<select><option>Option</option></select></div>
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happen and how to correct this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the `select`. The one that is not dynamic is formatted like so:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <label>Label</label>
    <select><option>Option</option></select>
</div>
```

And the dynamic ones are one liners like so:

```
<div class="form-inline"><label>Label</label><select><option>Option</option></select></div>
```

So use one way and the style (appearance) will be the same.

Here is an updated jsFiddle: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/4Uf2U/3/)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that indentation could change the rendering

Comment: No problem! Yeah I know.. Don't know why but you wont never forget it anymore ;).

Comment: Yeah I will not forget it by now. I can't find a way to use append to put the content on a new line and I don't really want to format it on only one line because it's really not readlable, have you an idea how to do ? I tried to add some \n and it works but maybe there is a more elegant solution ...